# Cartthrob order reports not exporting

Tags: cartthrob, shopping-cart

I'm new to Cartthrob and feel embarrassed to ask this, but for the life of me I just can't figure out how to get it to generate CSV reports. Under "Order Report" I fill in the fields and click the "Generate Report" or the "Export CSV" and each time the page just refreshes and all my selections and data are gone. What am I doing wrong? What should happen? Are the CSVs getting dumbed somewhere? If I try to enter a title it doesn't save either.

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Which version of Cartthrob is this? Pro 2.2.91 with Order Manager included?

Comment: Yes, the current version 2.2.9 with Order Manager included. Thanks for asking that - totally forgot to include that in the question.

Comment: Just a thought but is your PHP version 5.3 or newer?